# google analytics-multiple data streams for multiple URLs?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I want to use Firebase Analytics in my website in order to get some statistics for the visitors of each page (I don't want to track user journey in the site). I wanted to define multiple data streams (one for each url) in my google analytics dashboard, but then it warned me with the following message:

> In most cases, a single web stream will meet your measurement needs. Using multiple web streams to measure different pages or sites in a single user’s journey may lead to inconsistent results.

in my case-where I want to see the statistics of my site based on its pages (urls)-should I define multiple data streams?

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, it is not necessary to split based on the path in the web site.

You can in the Google Analytics console instead filter based on that path. This gives you the best of both worlds, as you can show stats for a specific path, but also for the site in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using separate data streams in a similar situation where we had a multilingual site with a domain-per-language.  The analytics dashboard lets you separate the data by domain, but the tools are bulky and don't seem available everywhere.

In short, creating a separate stream for data that is always going to be viewed separately can be a real convenience, even if it's not "the right way".

The main caveat from [the data-streams documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9679158?hl=en&utm_id=ad#data-streams) seems to be that you can miscount data.  For instance, a user switching from the English site to the French site will be counted as a visitor on each rather than as a single visit.  As long as you're aware of the data implications, you should be okay.